# Android passing large float arrays from native to java via jni. Getting error if over certain size

Tags: android, arrays, android-ndk, java-native-interface, limit

I am wanting to pass a single large array of floats anywhere up too and beyond float[100000].
I have a setup successfully passing an array of size 212. But any larger and it crashes giving the following error message in the logcat:

"Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xbe949000 (code=1)"

### My code

**Native function**

```
NIEXPORT jfloatArray JNICALL  Java_carron_graphics_benchmark_NativeWrapper_getArrayNative(JNIEnv * env, jclass cls) {

    int tempSize = mParticleSystem->mSizeOfSystem*2;

    jfloat cArray[tempSize];
    jsize len = sizeof(cArray);

    jfloatArray jArray = (*env).NewFloatArray(len);

    if (jArray != NULL) {

        jint i;

        for (i = 0; i < tempSize; i++) {
            cArray[i] = mParticleSystem->mParticlePositions[i];
        }
        (*env).SetFloatArrayRegion(jArray, 0, len, cArray);
    }
    return jArray;
}
```

**Java**
Pretty straight forward simply grabbing the array. If I create and pass a float array larger than 212 though I get the error as shown above.

```
float tempArray[] = NativeWrapper.getArrayNative();
```

**Has anyone encountered this problem or can see how I can get around this limit? Also I apologise if this question has been answered already, I could not find this specific issue nor an answer. Any help will be appreciated :)**

EDIT:

For updating a global jfloatArray to avoid the garbage collector when frequently fetching an array through jni.

```
static jfloatArray gArray = NULL;

JNIEXPORT jfloatArray JNICALL Java_carron_graphics_benchmark_NativeWrapper_getArrayNative(JNIEnv * env, jclass cls)  {
    int arrayLength = mParticleSystem->mSizeOfSystem*2;

    if (gArray == NULL)
    {
        // create array
        jfloatArray jArray;
        jArray = env->NewFloatArray(arrayLength);
        gArray = (jfloatArray)env->NewGlobalRef(jArray);
    }

    // Update global 
    env->SetFloatArrayRegion(gArray, 0, arrayLength, mParticleSystem->mParticlePositions);

    return gArray;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem with your code is that stack is limited in size. You can not put there large arrays (`jfloat cArray[tempSize]` variable). If you want to create large array, do that on heap, like Alex is showing you.

If `mParticleSystem->mParticlePositions` is float array then this code will be better:

```
int tempSize = mParticleSystem->mSizeOfSystem*2;
jfloatArray jArray = env->NewFloatArray(tempSize);

if (jArray != NULL)
{
    env->SetFloatArrayRegion(jArray, 0, tempSize, mParticleSystem->mParticlePositions);
}
return jArray;
```

If it is not float array then use following code, no need to create additional float array:

```
int tempSize = mParticleSystem->mSizeOfSystem*2;
jfloatArray jArray = env->NewFloatArray(tempSize);

if (jArray != NULL)
{
    if (float* ptr = env->GetFloatArrayElements(jArray, NULL))
    {
        for (int i=0; i<tempSize; i++)
        {
            ptr[i] = mParticleSystem->mParticlePositions[i];
        }
        env->ReleaseFloatArrayElements(jArray, ptr, JNI_COMMIT);
    }
}

return jArray;
```

**EDIT**

To store jArray somewhere else (for example globally) do following:

```
static jfloatArray gArray = NULL;

jfloatArray fun(...)
{
    jfloatArray jArray;

    if (gArray == NULL)
    {
        // create array
        jArray = env->NewFloatArray(tempSize);
        gArray = (jfloatArray)env->NewGlobalRef(jArray);
    }
    else
    {
        jArray = gArray;
    }

    // ... here fill/modify jArray
    // SetFLoatArrayRegion/GetFloatArrayElemeents/ReleaseFloatArrayElements

    return jArray;
}
```

When done free the memory:

```
void freeArray(...)
{
    env->DeleteGlobalRef(gArray);
    gArray = NULL;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for building on Alex's answer, together you identified all the issues. 

- I was using the wrong size for NewFloatArray
- I did not need to create a new array as I already had a perfectly good one already. Skipping this step avoided the stack memory and just used the much larger heap which I was already using without issue.

Thanks again, 
Matt

Comment: One further question if I may. Using the method your method above it works fine, though the garbage collection is running on overtime. Is there a way to keep jArray in scope so to reuse instead of going out of scope and recreate? @Alex

Comment: Yes, you can keep jArray somewhere else - global var, or member to some C++ struct or class. Only then you need to create global reference with env->NewGlobalRef to prevent from garbage collector freeing it. And after you're done - free its memory with env->DeleteGlobalRef.

Comment: Thanks Mārtiņš I see that NewGlobalRef is the answer, though I cannot seem to find a example of use on anything else but a jobject. Could you please direct me with the syntax of setting a NewGlobalRef with a jfloatArray.

// Global
jfloatArray mJArray;

// In an init function
mJArray = env->NewFloatArray(size*2); 
env->NewGlobalRef(mJArray);

this is obviously causing me a force close... :D

Comment: Thanks again Mārtiņš. I am unsure what the full use of jArray was after the init of the gArray. Due to this I was able to get all the needed functionality with the function I edited into my question.

Comment: Do you see any issue with the function I added?

Comment: Don't you need to do SetFloatArrayRegion also first time you call function (when gArray == NULL)? That's why I put fill/modify jArray after if condition.

Comment: Ah yes I see your logic now. With my setup it was not crucial that it was updated on the first call but I have now amended my solution to do so. I still don't fully understand why you were returning jArray instead of just using gArray, is there a reason for this?

Comment: No reason for returning jArray. It doesn't matter which one you return. They are both equal.

Comment: Then I think that is it! Thank you for answering my never ending questions, it is very appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not compile: you probably had

```
jfloat *cArray = new jfloat[tempSize];
```

in your compiled code.

The mistake in your code is in call to NewFloatArray(). You should call NewFloatArray(tempSize), not (sizeof(cArray)).

Also note that there is no need to work with intermediate copy of mParticleSystem->mParticlePositions. If it is an array of float, you can simply use it for SetFloatArrayRegion().

Comment: Thank you Alex you hit the nail on the head with your answer, and Mārtiņš helped with a little more explanation. 

Thanks again,
Matt

Comment: Please note that the dynamic variable array feature of G++ does not comply with ISO and is not portable.