# jni error passing large arrays from java to c

Tags: c, arrays, android-ndk, java-native-interface, native

I know this has been already asked, but my case is a 3D array, and I didn't manage to apply the solution given here: [Android passing large float arrays from native to java via jni. Getting error if over certain size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14116687/android-passing-large-float-arrays-from-native-to-java-via-jni-getting-error-if)

I'm facing similar problem, I can pass small arrays but not larger ones. I get `unpinedprimitivearray` error on logcat.

Here is my C code:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stddef.h>


JNIEXPORT jdouble JNICALL Java_com_example_invert_MainActivity_inv
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jobjectArray arr){
    double sum = 0;
    int i,j,k;

     jsize dim1 = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, arr);

       for (i=0; i<dim1; i++){

            jdoubleArray *line1 =   (*env)->GetObjectArrayElement(env, arr, i);
            int dim2 =       (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, line1);
            jdouble *pos1 = (*env)->GetDoubleArrayElements(env, line1, 0);

            for (j=0; j<dim2; j++){
                jdoubleArray *line2 =   (*env)->GetObjectArrayElement(env, line1, j);
                int dim3 =       (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, line2);
                jdouble *pos2 = (*env)->GetDoubleArrayElements(env, line2, 0);

                for (k=0; k<dim3; k++){
                                   sum += pos2[k];
                    }
                (*env)->ReleaseDoubleArrayElements(env, arr, pos2, 0);
                (*env)->ReleaseDoubleArrayElements(env, arr, line2, 0);
              }

            (*env)->ReleaseDoubleArrayElements(env, arr, pos1, 0);

            (*env)->ReleaseDoubleArrayElements(env, arr, line1, 0);
       }



    return sum;

}
```

And full Logcat output:

```
02-20 18:35:42.784: W/dalvikvm(9385): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
02-20 18:35:42.784: I/dalvikvm(9385): Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
02-20 18:35:42.784: W/dalvikvm(9385): VFY: unable to resolve interface method 14481: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
02-20 18:35:42.784: D/dalvikvm(9385): VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
02-20 18:35:42.784: I/dalvikvm(9385): Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
02-20 18:35:42.784: W/dalvikvm(9385): VFY: unable to resolve interface method 14485: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
02-20 18:35:42.784: D/dalvikvm(9385): VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
02-20 18:35:42.914: I/dalvikvm(9385): Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
02-20 18:35:42.914: W/dalvikvm(9385): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 406: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
02-20 18:35:42.914: D/dalvikvm(9385): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
02-20 18:35:42.914: I/dalvikvm(9385): Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
02-20 18:35:42.914: W/dalvikvm(9385): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 428: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
02-20 18:35:42.914: D/dalvikvm(9385): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
02-20 18:35:43.264: D/libEGL(9385): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno.so
02-20 18:35:43.284: D/libEGL(9385): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno.so
02-20 18:35:43.294: D/libEGL(9385): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so
02-20 18:35:43.304: I/Adreno-EGL(9385): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:316>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: LNXBUILD_AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_3.2.4.04.03.00.173.012+PATCH[ES]_msm8226_JB_3.2.4__release_ENGG ()
02-20 18:35:43.304: I/Adreno-EGL(9385): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: 20.00.01
02-20 18:35:43.304: I/Adreno-EGL(9385): Build Date: 02/27/14 Thu
02-20 18:35:43.304: I/Adreno-EGL(9385): Local Branch: 
02-20 18:35:43.304: I/Adreno-EGL(9385): Remote Branch: quic/jb_3.2.4
02-20 18:35:43.304: I/Adreno-EGL(9385): Local Patches: 7de55685a2714b78da20f2a126b0dd72b0d2c0c4 Merge "PROFILER: fix default enabled/disabled setting"
02-20 18:35:43.304: I/Adreno-EGL(9385):                  75d04ab84c7a68c72d92d59aae1827fcfef44b91 PROFILER: fix default enabled/disabled setting
02-20 18:35:43.304: I/Adreno-EGL(9385): Reconstruct Branch: LOCAL_PATCH[ES]
02-20 18:35:43.414: D/OpenGLRenderer(9385): Enabling debug mode 0
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.224: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.234: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x42514190) failed to find entry (valid=1)
02-20 18:35:44.244: E/dalvikvm(9385): JNI ERROR (app bug): local reference table overflow (max=512)
02-20 18:35:44.244: W/dalvikvm(9385): JNI local reference table (0x603c5f78) dump:
02-20 18:35:44.244: W/dalvikvm(9385):   Last 10 entries (of 512):
02-20 18:35:44.244: W/dalvikvm(9385):       511: 0x42519650 double[] (2 elements)
02-20 18:35:44.244: W/dalvikvm(9385):       510: 0x42519628 double[] (2 elements)
02-20 18:35:44.244: W/dalvikvm(9385):       509: 0x42519600 double[] (2 elements)
02-20 18:35:44.244: W/dalvikvm(9385):       508: 0x425195d8 double[] (2 elements)
02-20 18:35:44.244: W/dalvikvm(9385):       507: 0x425195b0 double[] (2 elements)
02-20 18:35:44.244: W/dalvikvm(9385):       506: 0x42519588 double[] (2 elements)
02-20 18:35:44.244: W/dalvikvm(9385):       505: 0x42519560 double[] (2 elements)
02-20 18:35:44.244: W/dalvikvm(9385):       504: 0x42519538 double[] (2 elements)
02-20 18:35:44.244: W/dalvikvm(9385):       503: 0x42519510 double[] (2 elements)
02-20 18:35:44.244: W/dalvikvm(9385):       502: 0x425194e8 double[] (2 elements)
02-20 18:35:44.244: W/dalvikvm(9385):   Summary:
02-20 18:35:44.244: W/dalvikvm(9385):         4 of java.lang.Class (4 unique instances)
02-20 18:35:44.244: W/dalvikvm(9385):         2 of java.lang.String (2 unique instances)
02-20 18:35:44.244: W/dalvikvm(9385):       480 of double[] (2 elements) (480 unique instances)
02-20 18:35:44.244: W/dalvikvm(9385):         1 of java.lang.String[] (2 elements)
02-20 18:35:44.244: W/dalvikvm(9385):         1 of com.example.invert.MainActivity
02-20 18:35:44.244: W/dalvikvm(9385):        23 of double[][] (21 elements) (23 unique instances)
02-20 18:35:44.244: W/dalvikvm(9385):         1 of double[][][] (30 elements)
02-20 18:35:44.244: E/dalvikvm(9385): Failed adding to JNI local ref table (has 512 entries)
02-20 18:35:44.244: I/dalvikvm(9385): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
02-20 18:35:44.244: I/dalvikvm(9385):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x41801710 self=0x417ec980
02-20 18:35:44.244: I/dalvikvm(9385):   | sysTid=9385 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1074262012
02-20 18:35:44.244: I/dalvikvm(9385):   | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=37 stm=11 core=3
02-20 18:35:44.244: I/dalvikvm(9385):   at com.example.invert.MainActivity.inv(Native Method)
02-20 18:35:44.244: I/dalvikvm(9385):   at com.example.invert.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:71)
02-20 18:35:44.244: I/dalvikvm(9385):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4476)
02-20 18:35:44.244: I/dalvikvm(9385):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18795)
02-20 18:35:44.244: I/dalvikvm(9385):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
02-20 18:35:44.244: I/dalvikvm(9385):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-20 18:35:44.244: I/dalvikvm(9385):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
02-20 18:35:44.244: I/dalvikvm(9385):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
02-20 18:35:44.244: I/dalvikvm(9385):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-20 18:35:44.244: I/dalvikvm(9385):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-20 18:35:44.244: I/dalvikvm(9385):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1225)
02-20 18:35:44.244: I/dalvikvm(9385):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1041)
02-20 18:35:44.244: I/dalvikvm(9385):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-20 18:35:44.244: E/dalvikvm(9385): VM aborting
02-20 18:35:44.244: A/libc(9385): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d (code=1), thread 9385 (.example.invert)
```

Can you please correct my code to deal with large arrays? waiting for your help.

Comment: Please paste the logcat output into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening is you are creating a lot of local references and failing to delete them.  Eventually the table fills up and the VM aborts.

Looking at the summary section of the failure, there are 480 instances of `double[]` and 23 instances of `double[][]`, so that's what you need to look at.

The `unpinPrimitiveArray` messages indicate that you are attempting to delete the local references, but failing to do so, because the value you are passing in can't be found.  Looking at your code, you seem to be passing the same array reference (`arr`) into every release call, which is incorrect.  You should be passing the array object you pinned, and the corresponding primitive array pointer.  Further, in some cases you're calling the wrong release function.

For example, this:

```
jdoubleArray *line2 =   (*env)->GetObjectArrayElement(env, line1, j);
int dim3 =       (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, line2);
jdouble *pos2 = (*env)->GetDoubleArrayElements(env, line2, 0);
...
(*env)->ReleaseDoubleArrayElements(env, arr, pos2, 0);
(*env)->ReleaseDoubleArrayElements(env, arr, line2, 0);
```

should be:

```
(*env)->ReleaseDoubleArrayElements(env, line2, pos2, 0);
(*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, line2);
```

`pos2` came from `line2`, so those values need to be passed to the same release call.  The `line2` reference is a `jobject`, not a primitive array, so the `DeleteLocalRef` call should be used.

You need a similar fix for `pos1` / `line1`.

See also the [JNI Tips](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html) page.

Answer (score 0):

You should not call `ReleaseDoubleArrayElements` for things that you didn't obtain using `GetDoubleArrayElements`.

For `line1` and `line2` you should just call `DeleteLocalRef`, not `ReleaseDoubleArrayElements`.